# Pandas - common values for a particular column in two distinct dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames structured like the following:

```
user_id movie_id    rating
438     588         5
758     588         5
913     588         5
1024    588         5
1214    588         5

user_id movie_id    rating
45      3578        3
321     3578        3
467     3578        3
758     3578        3
1024    3578        3
1381    3578        3
```

Is there a Pandas-native way to isolate in a `list` the values for `user_id` which appear in both DataFrames?

For the above example, the expected output would be:

```
[758, 1024]
```

--

*Note: in order to help bootstrap Data Science Stack Exchange, this question has been posted with more background on datascience.stackexchange.com - if you are also a user of DSSE please help this site growing [by answering directly there](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14817/pandas-get-feature-values-which-appear-in-two-distinct-dataframes)*

Comment: Regarding the note: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @ayhan this is just a way to advertise for dsse :) -- if I just wanted good answers I would have posted it on SO only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [numpy.intersect1d()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) method:

```
In [277]: np.intersect1d(a.user_id, b.user_id).tolist()
Out[277]: [758, 1024]
```

or [pd.core.common.intersection()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/common.py#L347) method, but it seems to be slow (at least on my notebook for `aa` and `bb` DataFrames [see setup below...]):

```
In [307]: pd.core.common.intersection(a.user_id, b.user_id).tolist()
Out[307]: [1024, 758]
```

**Timing** for `aa` DF (50K rows) and `bb` DF (60K rows):

```
In [294]: aa = pd.concat([a] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [295]: bb = pd.concat([b] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [296]: aa.shape
Out[296]: (50000, 3)

In [297]: bb.shape
Out[297]: (60000, 3)

In [298]: %timeit aa.ix[aa.user_id.isin(bb.user_id),'user_id'].tolist()
10 loops, best of 3: 41.8 ms per loop

In [299]: %timeit np.intersect1d(aa.user_id, bb.user_id).tolist()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.36 ms per loop

In [300]: %timeit pd.merge(aa, bb, on='user_id').user_id.tolist()
...
skipped
...
MemoryError:

In [308]: %timeit pd.core.common.intersection(aa.user_id, bb.user_id).tolist()
10 loops, best of 3: 52.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: and you omit you first solution - can you add timings?

Comment: @jezrael, it hangs on my notebook :)

Comment: No problem. Btw, it is interesting that merge fail for you :) , and numpy solution obviously is the fastest. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
print (df1.user_id.isin(df2.user_id))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: user_id, dtype: bool

print (df1[df1.user_id.isin(df2.user_id)])
   user_id  movie_id  rating
1      758       588       5
3     1024       588       5

print (df1.ix[df1.user_id.isin(df2.user_id),'user_id'])
1     758
3    1024
Name: user_id, dtype: int64

print (df1.ix[df1.user_id.isin(df2.user_id),'user_id'].tolist())
[758, 1024]
```

Another solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
print (pd.merge(df1,df2, on='user_id').user_id.tolist())
[758, 1024]
```